# How to refer to keyboard for System.setIn()

Tags: java

I have made System.in to read from a String. But now I want to make it read from the keyboard again. When I try to google it all i get back is "How to read line from keyboard in java" pretty much.

So what i want to do is:

```
     System.setIn(REFERENCE_TO_KEYBOARD);
```

Feels like it should be easy to find, maybe I just suck at googling.

Here is what I've done, i just want to edit the string before sending it.

```
 String message = "abc"
 ByteArrayInputStream bais =
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes());
            System.setIn(bais);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            message = scanner.nextLine();
            // here i want to edit the line
            System.out.println(message);
            scanner.close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done? Show your current code please?

Comment: [You don't need to "Thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: It shouldn't matter. i just need to know how to revert my change to System.in.

Comment: ([edit] your question to add necessary information, but I suppose you already know you should do that)

Comment: But it's not necessary information at all?

Comment: well I did it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset standard input and output in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366247/how-to-reset-standard-input-and-output-in-java)

Comment: But thanks for teaching me about `setIn`.

Comment: Thank's man! :)

Comment: You don't have to use `System.setIn` at all in your code above. Just use `new Scanner(bais)`. (Or even better, `new Scanner(message)`.) Your problem is non-existent.

Comment: (Google search tips: I searched for `java revert System.setIn site:stackoverflow.com` on Google and get the duplicate as the first result)